# css not rendered on all routes with express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

only base routes are rendered with css. so `/` , `/home` , `/about` and `/portfolio` have no problem. 
but `/portfolio/project1` or `about/biography` are rendered without css

this is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const xhbs = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.engine('handlebars', xhbs({
    defaultLayout:'main'
}));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

app.get('/portfolio', (req, res)=>{//css works fine on this route
        res.render('portfolio');
});    

app.get('/portfolio/project1', (req, res)=>{//css has no effect here
    res.render('project1');
});
```

and my files are structured this way

```
public
    css
        styles.css
views
    layouts
        main.handlebars
server
    server.js
```

Comment: I think without seeing your handlebars templates and file system this is a hard question to answer.

Comment: You should use css link relative to root like '/css/styles.css' this may work.

Comment: @ajitkumar you were right. please change this comment to an answer so that it gets accepted as the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use css link relative to root like '/css/styles.css' this may work.

**Explanation**: without '/' to the source address the request will go the current directory. eg. if make request to `css/style.css` and you are on path 'project/project1' then request to the `style.css` will be `project/project1/css/style.css` which will result in error `404`.

With '/' in the beginning the request will be relative to the public root. Hence from any path the request will always go to the root of the public.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base tag   in the head section of handlebars file

`<base href="http://localhost:5000">`

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute path for the static middleware

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: didn't work. as ajit kumar pointed above, the problem was that I was including css file in `main.handlebars `as `css/style.css`
but it should be `/css/styles.css`

Comment: yeah, the underlying problem was the same tho. you didn't use absolute paths